# CakePHP 3.x - viewBuilding()->setLayout('blank') not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I am attempting to set the layout to blank.ctp but it is not working, I have created a blank.ctp in src/Template/Layout but the following code is not working, as in the blank.ctp file is not being shown, the default layout is.

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['get']);
    $this->loadModel('AdminLTETasks');
    $adminLTETask = $this->AdminLTETasks->get($id);
    if ($this->AdminLTETasks->delete($adminLTETask)) {
        echo 'The admin l t e task has been deleted.';
    } else {
        echo 'The admin l t e task could not be deleted. Please, try again.';
    }

    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('blank');
}
```

I have also tried the deprecated method layout('blank') and it as well is not working

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['get']);
    $this->loadModel('AdminLTETasks');
    $adminLTETask = $this->AdminLTETasks->get($id);
    if($adminLTETask->user_id == $this->Auth->user('id')) {
        if ($this->AdminLTETasks->delete($adminLTETask)) {
            echo 'The admin l t e task has been deleted.';
        } else {
            echo 'The admin l t e task could not be deleted. Please, try again.';
        }
    }

    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('blank');
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error? Is the blank.ctp file getting loaded? Need more details.

Comment: The default layout is being shown

Comment: Any chance that the layout is being reset to default, like in a `beforeRender` callback or the `delete.ctp` itself?

Comment: @GregSchmidt you hit the nail right on the head, it was being overridden in the appcontroller beforeRender.... WOOOPS =] Thank you Greg

Answer (score 0):

try this ways if you have multi layout. 
And if you want it blank for the first time (not styling ... etc)

This is the sample controller you to blank or assign new layout. 
class FrontsController extends AppController {
    public $title;

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Auth->allow(['index']);
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('frontend');
}

public function index() {

}
```

}

And this sample of your frontend.ctp layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <?= $this->element('Fronts/head') ?>
 </head>
 <body>
   <?= $this->element('Fronts/header') ?>
     <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="content" class="container">
      <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
      <div class="row">
        <?= ($this->request->getParam('action') == 'index') ? 'LIST' : strtoupper($this->request->getParam('action')); ?>
        <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
      </div>
    </div>
     <?= $this->element('Fronts/footer') ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what the critical difference is between what you've provided and the OP's code? This looks to me like it's functionally the same as what they've already tried.

Comment: hello, I found out some layout(blank) doesn't support for cakephp 3. so I also use to do that too, but it turn me the same error ask he did. so my solution is this I create one empty layout for those view I don't want it. My example was the sample of how to use multi layout template like you have one project with front-end and back-end at the same repository and we want assign different layout for them. This my explanation. Thank you for you feedback. :)